# Removing sorting option for columns on the post lists page

Tags: wp-list-table

By default the title column on a post/page/custom post type page in WordPress admin area is sortable.

How can I disable the sorting option?

[image]

I think the question is clear but just to extend it a little bit.

I am customizing the custom post types page in the admin area.

**My code:**

```
add_filter( 'manage_sponsor_posts_columns', 'kiran_set_columns' );

function kiran_set_columns( $columns ) {
    $newColumns = array();
    $newColumns['title'] = 'Sponsor';
    return $newColumns;
}
```

I do not want the title column to provide the sorting feature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The filter hook `manage_edit-post_sortable_columns` contains all the columns, which are sortable. So you could hook into this filter and unset the `title`:

```
<?php

add_filter( 'manage_edit-post_sortable_columns', 'wse_240787' );
function wse_240787( $col ) {
    unset( $col['title'] );
    return $col;
}
```

This filter is documented in *wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php*:

> ```
>   /**
>      * Filters the list table sortable columns for a specific screen.
>      *
>      * The dynamic portion of the hook name, `$this->screen->id`, refers
>      * to the ID of the current screen, usually a string.
>      *
>      * @since 3.5.0
>      *
>      * @param array $sortable_columns An array of sortable columns.
>      */
> ```

```
$_sortable = apply_filters( "manage_{$this->screen->id}_sortable_columns", $sortable_columns );
```

Since our current screen Id is `edit-post` the filter is `manage_edit-post_sortable_columns`.

If you are using a custom post type, the screen ID would change to `edit-{$cpt_slug}`. For example for pages it would be `edit-page`. If your CPT is sponsor, it would be `edit-sponsor`. (Thanks @bravokeyl for pointing to this).

Comment: The screen for the OP might be different as that is a custom post type, so I guess it would be `manage_edit-sponsor_sortable_columns`.

Comment: You are right, will add this to my answer!

Comment: I didn't know that unset can be used for manage_edit-{cpt}_sortable_columns. Thanks for the help and all the info. Have a great day.